# "Escobar: Paradise Lost": who died?

Tags: plot-explanation, escobar-paradise-lost

### Note: this whole question is a spoiler.

The ending of the subject film is ambiguous, hence this question.

At the end of "Escobar: Paradise Lost", Maria sees that Nick's wound is fatal, or near fatal.  She runs to the gate of the Canadian embassy screaming for help, you hear (but cannot see) a vehicle approaching her.

Are we meant to assume that Maria is on Escobar's hit list and gets murdered at that point? What was the point of killing her?  Also, the hit squad presumably knew that Nick was in the church because they were parked outside. Were they respecting his right of sanctuary? Or are we meant to assume that Nick died by bleeding out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nick in all probability dies but Maria would likely have been picked up by one of Escobar's men.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that either Nick or Maria dies. The Director / Screenwriters know well that such starcrossed young lovers cannot die in a movie.Bad guys die as we know Uncle Pablo does and often the "loner--anti-hero dies" (which Nick is not) as a loner who is less than heroic or perfect Denzel Washington dies in Man on Fire.

In that last scene they should reshoot the end where Denzel hands over the little girl and gets in the car with the Los Banditos. What I hoped to happen was as soon as Denzel sat in the back seat and the car started to move and he died. His last move was to drop the cruxifix and necklace to the floor.

Now how about changing it to as Denzel takes his last breath from all the gunshot wounds, his hand drops the Cruxifix and chain but we suddenly realize that the chain is attached to the safety pin of a US Army M-67 hand grenade (the safety pin prevents the grenade from arming the timer which goes off in 10 seconds). The pin and chain fall to the floor. The camera shot goes to the girl and her Mom who see the car with hero Denzel and the crime crew suddenly blow to 500 pieces all over the landscape. Believe me (I was Army) armed and live hand grenade in a car would be one big MF of an explosion.

Back to the Movie:   But NEVER would Pablo kill his niece.It doesn't work that way with hispanic people. They have been so downtrodden for 300 years that Familia is EVERYTHING--they love their families and children very much-- and besides in the movies, you don't kill a pretty niece in real life Columbia or in a movie.
I liked the movie. Since it was wrapped around a real history event that is well documented--the killing of Pablo in 1993 one can relate to the timeline.
My view is that I liked Blow more. Both protagonists are real Pablo and George Jung who finally got out of Federal prison Sept 2015.  That movie really nails it--rarely do these kinds of people win---while they have tons of money in the end the forces of the law over the entire world are just too great. Had George been just a bit smarter (rarely are these people rocket scientists) he would have split up his huge profits in various banks i.e. Cayman, Switzerland, etc but being a dumb Rube Pothead he put $millions in the Panama bank of Noriega who just happened to get in the way of world commerce's need to expand the Panama Canal back in the 1990's. Mr. Bush, Senior decided he had enough of Noriega and George was just collateral damage when Bush and US Army took out Noriega.

Answer (score 0):

Nick wasn't murdered, but Maria was killed in front of the Canadian embassy.

Comment: You should expand your answer.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think Maria was killed at the gate and Nick was found and saved of his wound and he healed up. Then he finds out that Maria is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Nick dies, because you can see it in his face and hear him take his last breath. Marie is not killed, but is taken away to the family compound.

Comment: Please write broader answer why you think it is. The question asks more.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nick dies because, in the end, it shows images of him reunited with his already dead brother at the beach they both loved and considered their happy paradise during their life in Colombia.

Also, nobody escapes Don Pablo Escobar. So, he had to go.

Maria survives...